# How can I get next.js to copy over unused images into the build folder static/images/ even though they're not being used in the app?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

Currently Next.js doesn't copy over unused images when building the final application and this is great except that I need another version of my website's logo to be copied over.

I need the .jpg version of the logo copied over while my website only ever imports the .svg.

How can I get next.js to do this?

I tried importing the image in a component even though it was unused and since it was unused it was ignored.